# Where is the 'I/O Read Bytes' & 'I/O Write Bytes' in task manager in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Where are the 'I/O Read Bytes' & 'I/O Write Bytes' columns in task manager in Windows 8? In Windows 7 there was a list of columns where one can chose the columns to display. I can't find the equivalent in Windows 8?